# From a shell script, how to copy entire tree of files

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I want to check if a file exists, and if not, copy an entire tree of files from one location to another.  I imagine this is a little more complicated than a simple cp command, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's only a *little* more complicated than a simple `cp` command inasmuch as it's a near-simple `cp` command. `cp` under Linux has a recursive option so you can do:

```
cp -R dir1 dir2
```

See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) for details or execute `man cp` from a terminal window. To check if a file exists in `bash`, you can use:

```
if [[ -f file.txt ]] ; then
    # do something
fi
```

Execute `man bash` for details on `[[` or see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

Comment: Nice!  Does it keep the relative directory structure?

Comment: @coffee, yes, it maintains the structure.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you could write something like:

```
   cp -a ${SOURCE_DIR} ${DEST_DIR}
```

but again, this depends on the expect problem you have.